# Limiting distribution of $\frac {X_n -Y_m -(n-m)}{\sqrt{X_n+Y_m}}$ where $X_n,Y_m$ are independent Poisson

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_n$ , $Y_m$ be independent Poisson variables with means $n$, $m$.

$$\frac {X_n -Y_m -(n-m)}{\sqrt{X_n+Y_m}}$$

Find the limiting distribution as $n,m \to \infty$

I know that $\frac{X_n-n}{\sqrt{n}} \to N(0,1)$ but don't know what the next step would be.

Comment: Is $m$ fixed? Is the $Y_n$ in the denominator supposed to be $Y_m$ or is it really $Y_n$?

Comment: fairly sure it is $Y_m$ on the denominator

Comment: Yes $Y_m$ on the denominator

Comment: I think if $n,m \to \infty$ then the limiting distribution is $N(0,1)$. It's unclear to me what it is if $m$ is fixed and $n \to \infty$.

Comment: sorry I just fixed it, ,→∞

Comment: What does $n,m\to\infty$ mean? The result might depend on the order or the ratio in which they go to infinity. Or is it part of what you want to prove that it doesn't?

Comment: @joriki, The result cannot depend on the order or the ratio in which they go to infinity. If $X_n \xrightarrow{d}X$, $Y_n \xrightarrow{d}Y$, every $X_i$ do not depend on any $Y_j$, then for  any $k_n\to\infty$, $m_n\to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$, $\binom{X_{k_n}}{Y_{m_n}} \xrightarrow{d} \binom{X'}{Y'}$ where $X',Y'$ are independent with the same marginals as $X,Y$. This can be easily checked using multivariate characteristic functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First prove that 
$$
Z(n,m)=\frac {X_n -Y_m -(n-m)}{\sqrt{n+m}} \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal N(0,1).
$$
Use characteristic functions and Lévy's continuity theorem. Since for Poisson distribution $X\sim Poiss(\lambda)$ characteristic function is $\varphi_X(t)=e^{\lambda(e^{it}-1)}$ and $\varphi_{X-\lambda}(t)=e^{\lambda(e^{it}-1-it)}$, then
$$
\varphi_{Z(n,m)}(t) = \varphi_{X_n-n-(Y_m-m)}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n+m}}\right) = \varphi_{X_n-n}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n+m}}\right)\cdot \varphi_{Y_m-m}\left(-\frac{t}{\sqrt{n+m}}\right) = e^{n\left(e^{i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n+m}}}-1-i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n+m}}\right)}\cdot e^{m\left(e^{-i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n+m}}}-1+i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n+m}}\right)}
$$
Consider power of exponent: 
$$
n\left(e^{i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n+m}}}-1-i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n+m}}\right) + m\left(e^{-i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n+m}}}-1+i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n+m}}\right) = 
n\left(\color{green}{1}+ \color{red}{i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n+m}}}-\frac{t^2}{2(n+m)}+o\Bigl(\frac{t^2}{n+m}\Bigr)-\color{green}{1}-\color{red}{i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n+m}}}\right) + m\left(\color{green}{1}-\color{red}{i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n+m}}}-\frac{t^2}{2(n+m)}+o\Bigl(\frac{t^2}{n+m}\Bigr)-\color{green}{1}+\color{red}{i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n+m}}}\right) = -\frac{t^2}{2} + t^2\cdot o(1)
$$
We use Taylor series $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+o\bigl(\frac{x^2}{2}\bigr)$ as $x\to 0$.

So when $n+m\to\infty$
$$
\varphi_{Z(n,m)}(t) = e^{-\frac{t^2}{2} + t^2\cdot o(1)} \to e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} = \varphi_{\mathcal N(0,1)}(t). 
$$

Next, $X_n+Y_m$ have Poisson distribution with parameter $n+m$, therefore
$$
\frac{X_n+Y_m}{n+m} \xrightarrow{p} 1.
$$
Use then continuity of square root and Slutsky's theorem to conclude that 
$$
\frac {X_n -Y_m -(n-m)}{\sqrt{X_n+Y_m}} = \frac {X_n -Y_m -(n-m)}{\sqrt{n+m}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{X_n+Y_m}{n+m} }}\xrightarrow{d} \mathcal N(0,1).
$$

Comment: What is the easiest way to justify $(X_n+Y_m)/(n+m) \overset{p}{\to} 1$?

Comment: Oops, I see it now: law of large numbers

Comment: May I ask why didn't we use moment generating function instead of characteristic function?

Comment: @user3750556 Using characteristic functions or generating functions of moments is a matter of taste. You can do the same with mgf's by substituting $s=it$.

Comment: For "So when $m+n\to\infty$'', it is appropriate to change to "So when $\min(m,n)\to \infty$''.

Comment: @JGWang The limits are the same if one of variables tends to infinity but the second one is bounded. So it is not need to want that both variables increase.

Comment: @NCh Thank you. You are right.