# $Z_{n,m} = \frac {(X_n +Y_m) -(n+m)}{\sqrt{X_n+Y_m}}$ converges to $N(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem

Given $X_n \sim P(n), Y_m \sim P(m)$ independent. How can I see that $Z_{n,m} = \frac {(X_n +Y_m) -(n+m)}{\sqrt{X_n+Y_m}}$ converges to $N(0,1)$ when $n,m$ go to inifinity? I know that $Z_{n,m} \sim P(n+m)$, but I don't see how can I apply the central limit theorem here. I saw a proof for the convergence of a similar distribution here [Limiting distribution of $\frac {X_n -Y_m -(n-m)}{\sqrt{X_n+Y_m}}$ where $X_n,Y_m$ are independent Poisson](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3514308/limiting-distribution-of-frac-x-n-y-m-n-m-sqrtx-ny-m-where-x-n-y) but it involves characteristic functions. Is there a more straightforward way to do it in this case?

Comment: $X_n + Y_m$ is just the sum of $n+m$ independent variables with an identical Poisson(1) distribution. Divide by $n+m$ and you have an average to which you can apply a CLT?